# How can I stop my config from overriding new values?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

So i'm a bit new to the Bukkit API, so please don't go too hard on me, with that aside i've been making a plugin where i want the config able to be customized by the admins, but i've run into an issue that no matter what I do, it replaces the new values someone tries to enter into the config, with the defaults.

So here's a list i setup in the default config in the code itself:

```
PersonalBoosterTypes:
- 5#60
- 2#60
- 3#60
- 5#45
- 2#180
- 3#120
- 2#90
```

Now if i add a new value in the plugin config not in the code like so:

```
PersonalBoosterTypes:
- 5#60
- 2#60
- 3#60
- 5#45
- 2#180
- 3#120
- 2#90
- 3#180 // new value
```

and after that i reload the server, it deletes that value and keeps the defaults. I've put this method in my onEnable:

```
private void loadConfig() {
    this.getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);
    this.saveConfig();
}
```

Is there a other way to load the defaults without overriding or do i have to manually add every default with addDefault()?

Please help!
Cheers, Daniel

Comment: I've always found issues like this where the config is overriding what you want to be (a) frustrating, and (b) hard to solve. This doesn't help you get to an answer, but I just want you to know you we all share your pain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researching i've actually found the solution by myself and it's suprisingly simple, all i had to do is in my onDisable method, I've just needed to add these two lines:

```
this.reloadConfig();
this.saveConfig();
```

I was suprised at first, but it works as a charm, Hopefully this helps others to find this solution to the problem